# Solution for create optional Route parameter PHP

Tags: php, regex, routes

I created Route class for my PHP application. Everything ok, this's my function dispatch:

```
public function dispatch()
{
    //some code...
    $search = array();
    $regex = preg_replace_callback(
          '#{([\w]+)?(:([^/\(\)]*))?}#',
           function($m) use (&$search) {
               $search[$m[1]] = null;
               if (isset($m[3])) {
                   return '(?P<'.$m[1].'>'.$m[3].')';
               }
               return '(?P<'.$m[1].'>[^/\?]+)';
           },
           str_replace(array(')','/+'), array(')?','(/?|/.*?)'), $pattern)
    );
    $regex .= ($last === '/') ? '?' : '/?';
    $regex = '#^'.$regex.'$#i';
    if (preg_match($regex, $url, $matches)) {
        // some code...
    }
    // some code...
}
```

Now, i can use Route look like this:

```
$router = new Router();
$router->add('/', function() {
   echo 'Homepage';
});
$router->add('/user/{id}', function($id) {
   echo 'User ID: ' . $id;
});
```

Optional Route:

```
$router->add('/user(/{id})', function($id) {
    echo 'User ID: ' . $id;
});
```

It working, but i want change syntax from '/user(/{id})' to '/user/{id?}', how can i do that? I think maybe change regex '#{([\w]+)?(:([^/()]*))?}#' to something, but i can't. Somebody help me?

Comment: I think regex should be somthing like |user/d*/?| but not have proficiency in regexp so can't sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/cT5gF0/1) to match either: `\/\{(\w+)(\?)?\}`.

This will match any `/{param}` or `/{param?}`. You would check if the '?' was captured to check whether it's optional or not.

That expression will match parameters containing only letters, you could easily expand it to take whatever characters you would want by doing something like this: `\/\{([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_])(\?)?\}`